# Is it necessary to register transitive dependencies in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was creating my application, and now I have a problem with understanding whether it is necessary to register services in Asp.net Core. I understand that service registration is needed to establish a connection between interfaces and their implementation, so we can get instances of these interfaces in the controller constructor, but what about interfaces and services that are not used in the controller?

I hope to receive any information on my question.

Comment: Please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection for more information, and for DI in controllers see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have other services that *transitively* are being used by controllers, you can also register those with the ASP.NET Core services collection. This will also auto-wire those services.

Imagine that you have a Controller that depends on a service:

```
public MyController(IFoo foo)
```

You'd register the `IFoo` implementation with the services collection, as already suggested in the OP:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
```

What, however, happens if the `Foo` implementation depends on another service?

```
public Foo(IBar bar)
```

You can register that as well:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBar, Bar>();
```

If you don't, the system won't know how to create an `IBar` object, which means that it can't create an `IFoo` object, which means that it can't create a `MyController` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the concept. Plus, when I asked this question, I thought, why can't I create an interface, for example, to define photo parameters and implement it, and then use an instance of the object in another service, but this way I will take flexibility from the program.